# VLAN & VPN for IP Phone

Tags: networking, voip, vlan

I have a LAN with some IP phone and some PCs. This LAN is connected via VPN to another office.
For several reason I cannot change the IP address of the IP Phone (static) and for the PCs (DHCP): the IP addresses are in the same segment (`10.10.10.0/24`).

I want to create 2 VLANs:

- for the IP Phone
- for the data PC (to increase the QoS for IP phone).

Both VLANs must be connected to VPN/router that do not support VLAN.

I want to connect the IP Phone to the VLAN 20 via Untagged ports, the PC to the VLAN 10 via Untagged ports, and the VPN/router to another port that is related to VLAN 10 Untagged & VLAN 20 Untagged.

Now: All works fine, PC and VLAN do not interact each other. But is this a good configuration?